# Why am I getting this attribute error in Python?

Tags: python

Thanks in advance for any help, I know this is probably a newb question but I just can't find anything via search that seems to answer my question. This is the relevant part of the traceback:

```
  File "war.py", line 183, in __battle
    if (card1 > card2):
  File "war.py", line 24, in __lt__
    return self.int_id % 13 < other.int_id % 13
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'int_id'
```

I'm confused about what this means....what is the 'function' object? Also, why is calling **lt** from a line that's doing a greater than comparison? Why is this a problem now, given that I unit tested my Card class (of which card1 and card2 are instances of), including all rich comparison operators, and it passed?

These are the definition of the rich comparison methods in my Card class (int_id is, as you would probably guess, just an instance variable int):

(sorry the indenting below got messed up)

```
class Card():

    def __init__(self, int_id):
        self.int_id = int_id

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 < other.int_id % 13

    def __le__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 <= other.int_id % 13

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 == other.int_id % 13

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 != other.int_id % 13

    def __gt__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 > other.int_id % 13

    def __ge__(self, other):
        return self.int_id % 13 >= other.int_id % 13
```

Comment: Are you sure you defined int_id as a class variable?

Comment: @Florin, I'm sure I **didn't** define it as a class variable. As my question states, I intend it to be an instance variable -- it is first referenced and assigned in Card.__init__(), so that each instance of Card has its own int_id.

Comment: from the error, it looks like either `card1` or `card2` is a `function` and not a `Card`. That could be because of a simple typo elsewhere, for example `card2 = getMyOtherCard` instead of `card2 = getMyOtherCard()`

Comment: You should probably include your `__init__` code.

Comment: @Kevin, that's exactly what it was, I had just been staring at it too long to see it. Thank you. If you'll submit that as an answer I will accept it. :)

Comment: @Kevin obviously card1 here is a function because card1>card2 code produces __ lt __ method call

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the error `'function' object has no attribute 'int_id'`, I would guess that a function object is being compared against a Card in the line `if (card1 > card2):`. This might occur if one of the cards was mistakenly assigned as a function. For example, `card1 = getMyOtherCard` instead of `card1 = getMyOtherCard()`.

Answer (score 2):

`card1` has somehow come to refer to a function (have you left out parentheses on a function or method call?).

As a result, `card1 < card2` gets rearranged to `card2 < card1` (because `function` objects don't have comparison operators), which is why `__lt__` is being called.

From http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__:

> There are no swapped-argument versions of these methods (to be used when the left argument does not support the operation but the right argument does); rather, `__lt__()` and `__gt__()` are each other’s reflection [...]